# Conditional Formatting in openpyxl using CellIsRule removes quotes in formula breaking the file

Tags: python, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I'm using openpyxl to create an Excel file we currently produce manually.  I need to apply conditional formatting to a range of cells such that the cells will have light red fill and dark red text when the cell value is "R".  Here is the code:

```
    DARK_RED_TEXT = fonts.Font(color='9C0006')     
    LIGHT_RED_FILL = PatternFill("solid", fgColor='FFC7CE')
    rule_range = f'B2:B{self.ws.max_row-1}'
    self.ws.conditional_formatting.add(rule_range,
         CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=["R"], stopIfTrue=True, font=DARK_RED_TEXT, fill=LIGHT_RED_FILL)
```

The program runs without error and produces an Excel .xlsx file.  When I open it, Excel complains that the file has an error and offers to repair it in an attempt to open. The error message calls out the conditional formatting.

In looking at the sheet2.xml files in both the original manually produced Excel spreadsheet and the one I am creating I see the following conditional formatting statements, with a difference in the <formula> text:

original Excel file:

`<conditionalFormatting sqref="B2:B35">         <cfRule type="cellIs" dxfId="4" priority="6" operator="equal">             <formula>"R"</formula>         </cfRule>`
openpyxl produced file:

`<conditionalFormatting sqref="B2:B35">         <cfRule type="cellIs" priority="2" operator="equal" dxfId="1" stopIfTrue="1">             <formula>R</formula>         </cfRule>`

Openpyxl is removing the double quotes around the R in the formula.  I have tried wrapping the double quotes in single quotes '"R"' but get the same result.  I have also tried escaping the double quotes ""R"" but again get the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does openpyxl show you when you read the file?

Comment: I have not tried to open the output file using openpyxl.  Just to be clear, are you asking me to have a small python program call load_workbook, then check the conditional formatting on cell B2?

Comment: Your formula needs to be applied in quotes so **formula=["R"]** means the resulting formula is just R. If you want it to be R in double quotes then you need to include those. So either put the double quoted R in single quotes; **formula=['"R"']** or add delimited double quotes **formula=["\"R\""]**

Comment: @CharlieClark:  Thanks for the quick response earlier today.  I opened the output file using openpyxl and lo and behold, we have quoted "R".  Here is the pertinent information from ws.conditional_formatting._cf_rules:  type='cellIs', rank=None, priority=6, equalAverage=None, operator='equal', aboveAverage=None, dxfId=1, stdDev=None, stopIfTrue=None, timePeriod=None, text=None, percent=None, bottom=None, colorScale=None, dataBar=None, iconSet=None, formula=['"R"'], <openpyxl.formatting.rule.Rule object>

Comment: @moken:  I tried both of those as stated in the last paragraph, but neither worked.  I just tried it again, and this time it worked.  Must have been working on this too late last night and did something stupid.  Thanks for confirming this for me.